# Use of text() function when using xPath in dom4j

Tags: xpath, dom4j

I have inherited an application that parses xml using dom4j and xPath:

The xml being parsed is similar to the following:

```
<cache>
  <content>
    <transaction>
      <page>
        <widget name="PAGE_ID">WRK_REGISTRATION</widget>
        <widget name="TRANS_DETAIL_ID">77145</widget>
        <widget name="GRD_ERRORS" />
      </page>
      <page>
        <widget name="PAGE_ID">WRK_REGISTRATION</widget>
        <widget name="TRANS_DETAIL_ID">77147</widget>
        <widget name="GRD_ERRORS" />
      </page>
      <page>
        <widget name="PAGE_ID">WRK_PROCESSING</widget>
        <widget name="TRANS_DETAIL_ID">77152</widget>
        <widget name="GRD_ERRORS" />
      </page>
    </transaction>
  </content>
</cache>
```

Individual Nodes are being searched using the following:

```
String xPathToGridErrorNode = "//cache/content/transaction/page/widget[@name='PAGE_ID'][text()='WRK_DNA_REGISTRATION']/../widget[@name='TRANS_DETAIL_ID'][text()='77147']/../widget[@name='GRD_ERRORS_TEMP']";

org.dom4j.Element root = null;

SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document document = reader.read(new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlToParse.getBytes())));
root = document.getRootElement();

Node gridNode = root.selectSingleNode(xPathToGridErrorNode);
```

where xmlToParse is a String of xml similar to the excerpt provided above.

The code is trying to obtain the GRD_ERROR node for the page with the PAGE_ID and TRANS_DETAIL_ID provided in the xPath.

I am seeing an intermittent (~1-2%) failure (returned node is null) of this selectSingleNode request even though the requested node is in the xml being searched.

I know there are some gotchas associated with using text()= in xPath and was wondering if there was a better way to format the xPath string for this type of search.

Comment: It's possible that the problem could be due to the presence of fragmented (adjacent) text nodes in the tree. This isn't supposed to happen, but it does: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JAXEN-67

Comment: Yeah. You _could_ use some XPath magic like `following-sibling::` axes, or some sort of selecting multiple nodes and work on them, but this query is not bad, should work and is not replaceable without the use of `text()`. I think your best shot is updating to _dom4j v2.0.0 alpha 2_ and hoping the problem would be gone there.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I was aware of the adjacent text node issue with text() so the text in nodes that we search on have no spaces.  We are using dom4j.1.6.1.  Additionally the failure rate is approximately one in a thousand but it still results in 2 or 3 a day.  On a failure we print the xml being parsed and the xPath used to a log.  There is no commonality - the failures represent unique xml and xPath combinations.  I will try using the new dom4j v2.0.0. version and report back our findings.

Comment: Has dom4jv2.0.0 addressed your issue? I am facing the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607311/dom4j-xpath-truncating-results

Answer (score 0):

From your snippets, there is a problem regarding `GRD_ERRORS` vs. `GRD_ERRORS_TMP` and `WRK_REGISTRATION` vs. `WRK_DNA_REGISTRATION`.

Ignoring that, I would suggest to rewrite

```
//cache/content/transaction/page
  /widget[@name='PAGE_ID'][text()='WRK_DNA_REGISTRATION']
  /../widget[@name='TRANS_DETAIL_ID'][text()='77147']
  /../widget[@name='GRD_ERRORS_TEMP']
```

as

```
//cache/content/transaction/page
  [widget[@name='PAGE_ID'][text()='WRK_REGISTRATION']]
  [widget[@name='TRANS_DETAIL_ID'][text()='77147']]
  /widget[@name='GRD_ERRORS']
```

Just because it makes the code, in my eyes, easier to read, and expresses what you seem to mean more clearly: “the `page` element that has children with these conditions, and then take the widget with this `@name`.” Or, if that is closer to how you think about it,

```
//cache/content/transaction/page/widget[@name='GRD_ERRORS']
  [preceding-sibling::widget[@name='PAGE_ID'][text()='WRK_REGISTRATION']]
  [preceding-sibling::widget[@name='TRANS_DETAIL_ID'][text()='77147']]
```