# DOM4J Xpath Truncating Results

Tags: dom, xpath, dom4j

We are maintaining an application that heavily relies on DOM4J and Xpath. Once in a while we see a strange behaviors with results of XPath execution via DOM4J: The text result would simply be truncated.

We tried applying the recommendation provided here: http://www.mail-archive.com/dom4j-user@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02688.html

It seems the problem occurs less frequently but it still manifests itsself. Last time we got it, it was after applying Xpath on a the clone of a document parsed as indicated by the previous link.

This also seems to be similar to the issue mentioned here: [Use of text() function when using xPath in dom4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914486/use-of-text-function-when-using-xpath-in-dom4j)